# Getting org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.PotentialStubbingProblem: Strict stubbing argument mismatch

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am using public API Nutritionix in my application to get detailed information about food ingredients from their database. I want to test a method which is sending a POST request to public API to receive details about products nutritional values and later on, use them in the next process in my application.

My test class looks like:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class CaloriesServiceTest {

  @InjectMocks
  private CaloriesService caloriesService;

  @Mock
  private RestTemplate restTemplate;

  @Mock
  private NutritionixHeader nutritionixHeader;

  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() {
    caloriesService = new CaloriesService(nutritionixHeader, restTemplate);
  }

  @Test
  void receiveNutritionInformationFromAPI() {

    given(nutritionixHeader.getNutritionixAppId()).willReturn("secretID");
    given(nutritionixHeader.getNutritionixAppKey()).willReturn("secretKey");

    var meal1 = Meal.builder()
        .mealIngredients(List.of(RecipeIngredient.builder()
            .foodName("grilled fish")
            .build()))
        .build();
    var meal2 = Meal.builder()
        .mealIngredients(List.of(RecipeIngredient.builder()
            .foodName("eggs")
            .build()))
        .build();
    var meal3 = Meal.builder()
        .mealIngredients(List.of(RecipeIngredient.builder()
            .foodName("bacon")
            .build()))
        .build();

    var dailyMeals = DailyMeals.builder().dailyMeals(List.of(meal1, meal2, meal3)).build();

    var foodNutritional1 = FoodNutritional.builder().foodName("food name1").calories(11.1).build();
    var foodNutritional2 = FoodNutritional.builder().foodName("food name2").calories(22.2).build();
    var foodNutritional3 = FoodNutritional.builder().foodName("food name3").calories(33.3).build();
    var foodNutritional4 = FoodNutritional.builder().foodName("food name4").calories(44.4).build();

    HttpEntity<NutrientsBodyForRequest> requestBody =
        new HttpEntity<>(NutrientsBodyForRequest.builder()
            .query("grilled fish | eggs | bacon | burger")
            .build());

    given(restTemplate
        .exchange("https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/nutrients",
            HttpMethod.POST,
            requestBody,
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<FoodNutritional>>() {
            }))
        .willReturn(
            new ResponseEntity<List<FoodNutritional>>(
                List.of(
                    foodNutritional1,
                    foodNutritional2,
                    foodNutritional3,
                    foodNutritional4),
                HttpStatus.OK));

    //when
    List<FoodNutritional> foodsNutritional =
        caloriesService.receiveNutritionInformationFromAPI(dailyMeals);

    assertThat(foodsNutritional.get(0).getBrandName(), is("grilled fish"));
    assertEquals(3, foodsNutritional.size());

  }

}
```

Unfortunetely, when I am running above test I am receiving an exception like:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.PotentialStubbingProblem: 
Strict stubbing argument mismatch. Please check:
 - this invocation of 'exchange' method:
    restTemplate.exchange(
    "https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/nutrients",
    POST,
    <com.application.meal.NutrientsBodyForRequest@3c486eb1,[]>,
    ParameterizedTypeReference<java.util.List<com.application.meal.FoodNutritional>>
);
    -> at com.application.meal.CaloriesService.receiveNutritionInformationFromAPI(CaloriesService.java:45)
 - has following stubbing(s) with different arguments:
    1. restTemplate.exchange(
    "https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/nutrients",
    POST,
    <com.application.meal.NutrientsBodyForRequest@afd496eb,[]>,
    ParameterizedTypeReference<java.util.List<com.application.meal.FoodNutritional>>
);
      -> at com.application.meal.CaloriesServiceTest.receiveNutritionInformationFromAPI(CaloriesServiceTest.java:69)
Typically, stubbing argument mismatch indicates user mistake when writing tests.
Mockito fails early so that you can debug potential problem easily.
```

My service looks like:

```
@Service
public class CaloriesService {

  private NutritionixHeader nutritionHeaderParam;

  private RestTemplate restTemplate;

  public CaloriesService(NutritionixHeader nutritionHeaderParam,
      RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    this.nutritionHeaderParam = nutritionHeaderParam;
    this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
  }

  private String prepareFoodNamesForRequest(DailyMeals dailyMeals) {
    return dailyMeals.getDailyMeals()
        .stream()
        .map(Meal::getMealIngredients)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .map(RecipeIngredient::getFoodName)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" | "));
  }


  public List<FoodNutritional> receiveNutritionInformationFromAPI(DailyMeals dailyMeals) {

    String foodNamesForRequest = prepareFoodNamesForRequest(dailyMeals);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("x-app-id", nutritionHeaderParam.getNutritionixAppId());
    headers.set("x-app-key", nutritionHeaderParam.getNutritionixAppKey());

    HttpEntity<NutrientsBodyForRequest> request =
        new HttpEntity<>(NutrientsBodyForRequest.builder()
            .query(foodNamesForRequest)
            .build(), headers);

    ResponseEntity<List<FoodNutritional>> response =
        restTemplate
            .exchange(
                "https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/nutrients",
                HttpMethod.POST,
                request,
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<FoodNutritional>>() {
                });

    return response.getBody();
  }
}
```

My component classes are as follows:

DailyMeals.class

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Builder
class DailyMeals {

  @Id
  private Long id;
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "dailyMeals")
  List<Meal> dailyMeals;
}
```

FoodNutritional.class

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class FoodNutritional {

  @JsonProperty("food_name")
  private String foodName;

  @JsonProperty("brand_name")
  private String brandName;

  @JsonProperty("serving_qty")
  private Integer servingQuantity;

  @JsonProperty("serving_unit")
  private String servingUnit;

  @JsonProperty("serving_weight_grams")
  private String servingWeightGrams;

  @JsonProperty("nf_calories")
  private Double calories;

  @JsonProperty("nf_total_fat")
  private Double totalFat;

  @JsonProperty("nf_saturated_fat")
  private Double saturatedFat;

  @JsonProperty("nf_cholesterol")
  private Double cholesterol;

  @JsonProperty("nf_sodium")
  private Double sodium;

  @JsonProperty("nf_total_carbohydrate")
  private Double totalCarbohydrate;

  @JsonProperty("nf_dietary_fiber")
  private Double dietaryFiber;

  @JsonProperty("nf_sugars")
  private Double sugars;

  @JsonProperty("nf_protein")
  private Double protein;

  @JsonProperty("nf_potassium")
  private Double potassium;
}
```

Meal.class

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Getter
@Builder
@Entity
public class Meal {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "meal")
  List<RecipeIngredient> mealIngredients;
}
```

EDIT:

For `@Abhiram` I am attaching and IntelliJ complain about your suggested piece of code

[image: error]

Edit2: After a little more thought I think that there is a problem with different HashCode of the object which I am passing as a body: `NutrientsBodyForRequest@3c486eb1,[]` and `NutrientsBodyForRequest@afd496eb,[]`, any suggestions if it possible that this is a source of a problem?

All I want to achieve is fix this error and check in a test if mocked service will return the desired result. I will be grateful for a suggestion on how to reach a goal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After cooperation with `@Abhiram` fortunately, I found the solution.

There was missing an `ArgumentMatcher` for parameters in my mock.

```
given(restTemplate
        .exchange(eq("https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/nutrients"),
            ArgumentMatchers.eq(HttpMethod.POST),
            ArgumentMatchers.any(),
            ArgumentMatchers.<ParameterizedTypeReference<List<FoodNutritional>>>any()))
        .willReturn(
            new ResponseEntity<List<FoodNutritional>>(
                foodsNutritionalStabData(),
                HttpStatus.OK));
```

Below approach solved a problem. Thank you so much for commitment.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "new ParameterizedTypeReference>() {}" , set up your mock to match ANY parameter of that type.

Instead of

```
given(restTemplate
        .exchange("https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/nutrients",
            HttpMethod.POST,
            requestBody,
>>>>>>>>>>  new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<FoodNutritional>>() { 
            }))
        .willReturn(
            new ResponseEntity<List<FoodNutritional>>(
                List.of(
                    foodNutritional1,
                    foodNutritional2,
                    foodNutritional3,
                    foodNutritional4),
                HttpStatus.OK));
```

Something like:

```
 given(restTemplate
      .exchange(eq("https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/natural/nutrients"),
            eq(HttpMethod.POST),
            eq(requestBody),
            Mockito.any())
        .willReturn(
            new ResponseEntity<List<FoodNutritional>>(
                List.of(
                    foodNutritional1,
                    foodNutritional2,
                    foodNutritional3,
                    foodNutritional4),
                HttpStatus.OK));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. You mean that I suppose to replace it to sth like: `any(FoodNutritional.class)` or something different?

Comment: @Ab
Unfortunately not working, I am using import `import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.any;` and with this IntelliJ underline line `any()` with type with the message: `cannot select from parametrized type`

Comment: Try using the ArgumentMatcher class instead of hamcrest:  https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html

Comment: I tried. It still complains about one single line of your suggested code. Post edited with error message.

Comment: Got it. Try using any() without any arguments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200224/discussion-between-abhiram-and-martin).